# How does masked_lm_labels argument work in BertForMaskedLM?

Tags: nlp, language-model, bert-language-model, mlmodel

```
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertForMaskedLM
import torch

tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
model = BertForMaskedLM.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

input_ids = torch.tensor(tokenizer.encode("Hello, my dog is cute", add_special_tokens=True)).unsqueeze(0) # Batch size 1
outputs = model(input_ids, masked_lm_labels=input_ids)

loss, prediction_scores = outputs[:2]
```

This code is from huggingface transformers page. https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/bert.html#bertformaskedlm

I cannot understand the `masked_lm_labels=input_ids` argument in `model`. 
How does it work? Does it means that it will automatically mask some of the text when `input_ids` is passed?

Answer (score 0):

The first argument is the masked input, the `masked_lm_labels` argument is the desired output.

The `input_ids` should be masked. In general, it is up to you how you do the masking. In the original BERT, they choose 15% tokens and the following with them, either

- Use `[MASK]` tokens; or
- Use a random token; or
- Keep the original token unchanged.

This modifies the input, so you need to tell your model what original non-masked input, which is the `masked_lm_labels` argument. Note also, that you do not want to compute the loss only for the tokens that were actually chosen for masking. The rest of the tokens should be replaced with an index `-100`.

For more details, [see the documentation](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/bert.html#transformers.BertForMaskedLM.forward).