# How to calculate perplexity of a sentence using huggingface masked language models?

Tags: nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, transformer-model

I have several masked language models (mainly Bert, Roberta, Albert, Electra). I also have a dataset of sentences. How can I get the perplexity of each sentence?

From the huggingface documentation [here](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/perplexity) they mentioned that perplexity "is not well defined for masked language models like BERT", though I still see people somehow calculate it.

For example in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63030692/how-do-i-use-bertformaskedlm-or-bertmodel-to-calculate-perplexity-of-a-sentence) question they calculated it using the function

```
def score(model, tokenizer, sentence,  mask_token_id=103):
  tensor_input = tokenizer.encode(sentence, return_tensors='pt')
  repeat_input = tensor_input.repeat(tensor_input.size(-1)-2, 1)
  mask = torch.ones(tensor_input.size(-1) - 1).diag(1)[:-2]
  masked_input = repeat_input.masked_fill(mask == 1, 103)
  labels = repeat_input.masked_fill( masked_input != 103, -100)
  loss,_ = model(masked_input, masked_lm_labels=labels)
  result = np.exp(loss.item())
  return result

score(model, tokenizer, '我爱你') # returns 45.63794545581973
```

However, when I try to use the code I get `TypeError: forward() got an unexpected keyword argument 'masked_lm_labels'`.

I tried it with a couple of my models:

```
from transformers import pipeline, BertForMaskedLM, BertForMaskedLM, AutoTokenizer, RobertaForMaskedLM, AlbertForMaskedLM, ElectraForMaskedLM
import torch

1)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bioformers/bioformer-cased-v1.0")
model = BertForMaskedLM.from_pretrained("bioformers/bioformer-cased-v1.0")
2)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("sultan/BioM-ELECTRA-Large-Generator")
model = ElectraForMaskedLM.from_pretrained("sultan/BioM-ELECTRA-Large-Generator")
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61470768/how-does-masked-lm-labels-argument-work-in-bertformaskedlm) SO question also used the `masked_lm_labels` as an input and it seemed to work somehow.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is a paper [Masked Language Model Scoring](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.14659) that explores pseudo-perplexity from masked language models and shows that pseudo-perplexity, while not being theoretically well justified, still performs well for comparing "naturalness" of texts.

As for the code, your snippet is perfectly correct but for one detail: in recent implementations of Huggingface BERT, `masked_lm_labels` are renamed to simply `labels`, to make interfaces of various models more compatible. I have also replaced the hard-coded `103` with the generic `tokenizer.mask_token_id`. So the snippet below should work:

```py
from transformers import AutoModelForMaskedLM, AutoTokenizer
import torch
import numpy as np

model_name = 'cointegrated/rubert-tiny'
model = AutoModelForMaskedLM.from_pretrained(model_name)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)

def score(model, tokenizer, sentence):
    tensor_input = tokenizer.encode(sentence, return_tensors='pt')
    repeat_input = tensor_input.repeat(tensor_input.size(-1)-2, 1)
    mask = torch.ones(tensor_input.size(-1) - 1).diag(1)[:-2]
    masked_input = repeat_input.masked_fill(mask == 1, tokenizer.mask_token_id)
    labels = repeat_input.masked_fill( masked_input != tokenizer.mask_token_id, -100)
    with torch.inference_mode():
        loss = model(masked_input, labels=labels).loss
    return np.exp(loss.item())

print(score(sentence='London is the capital of Great Britain.', model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer)) 
# 4.541251105675365
print(score(sentence='London is the capital of South America.', model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer)) 
# 6.162017238332462
```

You can try this code in Google Colab by running [this gist](https://gist.github.com/avidale/f574c014cd686709636b89208f2259ce).

Comment: This is great!! Thanks a lot. One question, this method seems to be very slow (I haven't found another one) and takes about 1.5 minutes for each of my sentences in my dataset (they're quite long). Any idea on how to make this faster? I suppose moving it to the GPU will help or somehow load multiple sentences and get multiple scores? Though I'm not too familiar with huggingface and how to do that

Comment: To use GPU, call `model.cuda()` after the model initialization, and replace `model(masked_input, labels=labels)` with `model(masked_input.cuda(), labels=labels.cuda())`. This will do the trick. But beware that most BERT-like models do not support texts longer than 512 tokens (~2000 characters), and that long texts eat up lots of GPU memory. 
And consider investing some time in learning `pytorch` and specifically the `transformers` library, because debugging neural networks on GPU requires some experience.

Comment: Thanks a lot again!! This cuts it down from 1.5 min to 3 seconds : )

Comment: @DavidDale how does this scale to a set of sentences (say a test set)? Should you take average over perplexity value of individual sentences? or first average the loss value over sentences and then exponentiate?

Comment: @dnivog the exact aggregation method depends on your goal. Typically, averaging occurs before exponentiation (which corresponds to the geometric average of exponentiated losses). 
The rationale is that we consider individual sentences as statistically independent, and so their joint probability is the product of their individual probability. Thus, by computing the geometric average of individual perplexities, we in some sense spread this joint probability evenly across sentences.

Comment: Of course, my reasoning above is purely metaphorical, because pseudo-perplexity from MLMs is not a true probability.

Comment: @DavidDale Thanks again for this. I was wondering, is it possible to extend this function to accept a batch of sentences? I'm having some trouble with the dimensions. e.g., `my_sentences =  ["London is the capital of Great Britain.", "London is the capital of South America.", "this is a third sentence"] `, and say, take the average over the perplexities as you mentioned to dnivog

Comment: @Penguin An easy and safe method to do this is just to write a loop over multiple sentences.