# Running batch perplexity with transformer model

Tags: pytorch, batch-processing, huggingface-transformers, torch, bert-language-model

I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70464428/how-to-calculate-perplexity-of-a-sentence-using-huggingface-masked-language-mode) to calculate perplexity of the sentence. However, I would love to do it in batch rather than with only single sentence.

I think I am very close, but I don't know why exactly it fails. This is what I have:

```
def _score1(self, sentences: List[str]) -> float:
    """
        Creates perplexity score of single sentence given model and tokenizer
        this must be improved by using a bulk inference technique
        is slow as of now.
    """
    tensor_input = self.tokenizer(sentences, return_tensors='pt')
    mask = [m[:-1].diag(1)[:-2] for m in tensor_input["attention_mask"]]
    repeat_inputs = [
        tinp.repeat(tinp.size(-1)-2, 1) for tinp in tensor_input["input_ids"]
    ]

    masked_inputs = [
        rpinp.masked_fill(msk == 1, self.tokenizer.mask_token_id)
        for rpinp, msk in zip(repeat_inputs, mask)
    ]
    labels = [
        rpinp.masked_fill( mpinp != self.tokenizer.mask_token_id, -100)
        for rpinp, mpinp in zip(repeat_inputs, masked_inputs)
    ]
    config1 = {
        "input_ids": torch.stack(masked_inputs, dim=0),
        "labels": torch.stack(labels, dim=0),
    }
    # this works but I only get a single value of loss as it is treating multiple sentences as one
    config2 = {
        "input_ids": torch.cat(masked_inputs, dim=1),
        "labels": torch.cat(labels, dim=1),
    }

    # config = {
    #     "input_ids": masked_inputs,
    #     "labels": labels,
    # }

    with torch.inference_mode():
        losses = self.model(**config).loss
        print(losses)
    return np.exp(loss.item())
```

As you can see, I am struggling to create a good config/merging mechanism for this to work.

Here are my findings:

1. If I simply use the list, I get a doesn't have .size() attribute error
2. If I use the cat method, I get a single value of loss which is because it treats the sentences as a single entity. This is not something desirable
3. If I use the stack method, I get a size mismatch error

```
File "site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
  return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "site-packages/transformers/models/distilbert/modeling_distilbert.py", line 580, in forward
  embeddings = self.embeddings(input_ids, inputs_embeds)  # (bs, seq_length, dim)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
  return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "site-packages/transformers/models/distilbert/modeling_distilbert.py", line 134, in forward
  embeddings = input_embeds + position_embeddings  # (bs, max_seq_length, dim)
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (34) must match the size of tensor b (32) at non-singleton dimension 2
```